Pass frontmatter variables to scripts using data-attribute and use in JavaScript Class
I have the following Astro component:
   ---
    type Props = {
      uuid: string;
    };
    
    const { uuid } = Astro.props;
    ---
    
    <div class="my-feature" data-uuid={uuid} id="my-feature"></div>
    
    <script is:inline src={import.meta.env.MY_SCRIPT}></script>
    
    <script>
      import { MyFeatureHelper } from '@/scripts/my-helper';
    
      let myFeature;
    
      const ref = document.getElementById('my-feature');
    
      myFeature = new MyFeatureHelper(ref as HTMLDivElement, {
        uuid: this?.ref.uuid,
      });
    
      myFeaturer.build();
    
    </script>

I need to pass uuid prop to the <script> tag without define:vars as described here because then my script will be treated as is:inline and I can't import the JavaScript Class MyFeatureHelper, which I need.
How can I get access to uuid and use it like e.g. uuid: this?.ref.uuid, using the data-attribute trick?
How do I get this to work?

Try: uuid: ref.dataset.uuid. Also I think you have a typo - my-container should be my-feature.

See Astro docs where there is an example on how to do this with a basic web component.
Alternatively, the following should work:
---
type Props = {
  uuid: string;
};

const { uuid } = Astro.props;
---

<div data-uuid={uuid} id="my-feature"></div>

<script>
  const uuid = document.getElementById('my-feature')?.dataset.uuid
</script>


thanks but because I add an attribute to the script tag <script data-uuid={uuid}> I cannot import a script import { MyFeatureHelper } from '@/scripts/my-helper'; in between the script tags (see my question). I also get this hint from IDE: This script will be treated as if it has the is:inline` directive because it contains an attribute. Therefore, features that require processing (e.g. using TypeScript or npm packages in the script) are unavailable. See docs for more details: docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/….`?

oh right, I edited my answer.

Ok then I get Property 'uuid' does not exist on type 'DOMStringMap | undefined'.?

That's a TypeScript error warning you of the possibility that the element in question might be undefined. Edited again...

btw. repro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-51x4t5?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FTest.astro

Thanks. Like this const uuid = document.getElementById('my-feature')?.dataset.uuid!;, it's working! Great

And what about placing all javascript code in the frontmatter and then call the component like <MyFeature client:only />, with the client:only directive. Would that also be an option? Then I don't have to do the dataset trick etc. Or is that a wrong approach?

sure, basically the more code you can execute on the server (i.e. in the frontmatter) instead of having to send it to the browser for your users to download, the better. But presumably, myFeaturer.build does something interactive in the browser and you have no choice?
btw. if this answered the question, feel free to accept/upvote it...

one question. Now I added in my Layout.astro a script tag to load an external script: <script is:inline src="https://external-script"></script>. But now this script is added on every page from Layout.astro. I need the script in the html head tag. Is it possible to add it by an Astro component so it's only rendered when that component is used?

yes, just move it there?

Yeah correct, sorry to inform you. And the is:inline directive is needed. Then it's working fine. Thanks

question. I'm importing the external script (see last comment), by an environment variable. Do I have to prefix it with PUBLIC as describes here?

regarding your example. Is it possible to have the uuid as an id instead of  my-feature? Like:  <div data-uuid={uuid} id={uuid}></div>. How to make this work? Because I can't use const ref = document.getElementById(uuid);? Because when I have multiple of this features per page, currently only the first one is working.

per html standard the id attribute needs to be unique in the page, so no.

But in React app with React useRef and then ref.current it's working fine.
